# Mail.app crashes - then bogus display and corrupted cache

Tags: macos, mail.app, crash

Since the last Mavericks update (10.9.2) and Mail.app update coming with it (7.2 - 1874) my mail application is regularly behaving badly.

Nearly everyday I face crashing and then display issues:

- Mail.app crashes at random times,
- the list of messages is not refreshed when deleting a message or when a new one comes in,
- navigating in the list of messages is messy (you click on one message, it is the next or previous one that is being selected),
- the main window is displayed like out of focus (greyed upper left corner red/yellow/green buttons),
- composing a new message is impossible because the recipient field is not available,
- and other weird display issues.

Quitting Mail.app, deleting the `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail` folder and restarting the application usually solves the display issue.  At least until the next crash.

Rebuilding the mailboxes, waiting for it to finish, quitting Mail.app and then restarting usually also solves the issue.  But for it to re-appear after the next crash.

I also noticed that this behavior tend to appear more when I use the combined Mail.app smart folder.  I have 4 different smart folders and usually read my emails from the top level smart folders, combining the elements from all 4 smart folders.

I've been using Mail.app for years (back from Leopard I think) and never faced this issue before.  And I've not done any major configuration change lately.

I'm using one plugin: [GPGMail](https://gpgtools.org/), in its latest version which is said to be Mavericks compatible. Re-installing or completely removing GPG Mail didn't make things go better.

Has anyone else experienced this type of behaviour?  Do you know any other way to reset the Mail.app state to a cleaner set up? (without wiping out all the accounts configuration)  Would that be a known Mail.app bug that hopefully will get corrected in the next version?

Comment: No, it does not work better re-installing or completely removing GPG Mail.

Comment: Yes, rebuilding all mailboxes didn't change things.

Comment: Not sure, but try repairing your permissions in disk utility.

Comment: Rebuilding mailboxes helps a bit with the issue, but not quite solves it.